# Is thinking about curse puts curse on someone?

Tags: allah

I imagined my mom cursed me. Will it put an actual curse on me?

Comment: According what logic would it do? Please do some prior research before asking a question. And show us where you got stuck and explain why do you think this would be the case.

Answer (score 0):

Just because someome imagines something that doesn't become reality.Only when your mom really curses, you need to worry. Until then get yourself busy with Audhu billahi minas shaithaan nirrajeem.